# Finding mailserver send logs

Tags: php, email, cpanel, logging

I use a hosting company and use PHP mail() script to send mail. Is there a records somewhere on my server that I can find all the mail sent? Where would I look? cPanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to ask your hosting company. These kinds of logs are usually not exposed in shared hosting - I've never seen it happen.

Related:

- [Get log of mail sent with mail() from PHP (sendmail?)](https://serverfault.com/questions/154212/get-log-of-mail-sent-with-mail-from-php-sendmail)